# Word for a product that is instantly usable

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe products that can be used out of the box with minimal configuration.

In my tip of the tongue memory this word may contain *keychain* as a subword or else something involving the metaphor of plugging a key into a socket and then the product just runs. Unfortunately, my memory is failing me now.

Comment: What's wrong with "Out-of-the-box functional"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_box_(feature)

Comment: We buy things, *off the shelf*, which means it does not have to be made specially. Not exactly the same thing, but close.

Comment: You could always go with metaphorically extended [***plug-and-play***](http://www.cnbc.com/2016/12/22/plug-and-play-anaerobic-digestion-turns-your-waste-into-biogas.html)

Comment: _**Instant noodles/coffee**_ comes to mind.

Comment: What kind of product is it? Please specify. Else, the question may be closed as "too broad".

Comment: Yep, "out of the box" is the usual idiom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you specify the type of products, it's difficult to narrow down the list of possible answers. But regarding your guess with "key" as a part of the term, consider:

***Turnkey*** -- [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/turnkey)

> (adj.) 3. fully equipped; ready to go into operation: *"a turnkey business."*

Comment: @theideasmith glad that was helpful. I am a civil engineer, and I immediately remembered ["turnkey contract"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turnkey-contract).

Comment: I'm writing documentation for my open source project and want it to be" turnkey operatable"

Comment: @theideasmith call it a turnkey project, then.

Comment: @NVZ - And I remember "turnkey" from jail.